# Remove the comma in the first column in .csv file using bash code

Tags: csv, sed

I have a data as follows;
12432,20230

I want to remove the comma and replace it with space and want the output as follows;
12432 20230

I used the following code;

```
sed ’s/,/ /g’ file.csv > file.geno
```

but it gives error as;

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `�'

Comment: do you need single quotes around the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using "smart quotes", `’`, instead of single quotes, `'`, just fix that and your syntax error will go away, i.e. instead of:

```
sed ’s/,/ /g’ file.csv > file.geno
```

use:

```
sed 's/,/ /g' file.csv > file.geno
```

You don't need the `g` at the end btw since you only have 1 comma in your input.